# SetState error when user login returns errors

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I've created a login page that takes a user from public to authenticated routes which works well. If there is an error with login (eg. email not found) I get the error in console `Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the LoginForm component.`.

I think it might be related to how I use createContainer in the `App`.

I believe the problem is related to the way meteor passes `Meteor.loggingIn();` equals `true` before it has heard back from the server. If there is an error the `true` quickly changes to `false`, which I think leads to the page reloading.

I would like to be able to use `this.setState({ loginError: error.reason });` so I can tell the user what went wrong.

Any suggestions.

Path: `App.jsx`

```
const App = appProps => (
  <Router>
    <Grid className="main-page-container">
      <Switch>
        <Authenticated exact path="/" component={Home} {...appProps} />
        <Public exact path="/login" component={Login} {...appProps} />
      </Switch>
    </Grid>
  </Router>
);


App.propTypes = {
  loggingIn: PropTypes.bool,
  authenticated: PropTypes.bool
};


export default createContainer(() => {
  const loggingIn = Meteor.loggingIn();
  return {
    loggingIn,
    authenticated: !loggingIn && !!Meteor.userId()
  };
}, App);
```

Path: `Public.jsx`

```
const Public = ({ loggingIn, authenticated, component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      if (loggingIn) return <div />;
      return !authenticated ?
      (React.createElement(component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated })) :
      (<Redirect to="/" />);
    }}
  />
);

Public.propTypes = {
  loggingIn: PropTypes.bool,
  authenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  component: PropTypes.func
};

export default Public;
```

Path: `LoginForm.jsx`

```
export default class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      errors: {},
      password: '',
      loginError: ''
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox'
      ? target.checked
      : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({[name]: value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      errors: {}
    }, function() {
      var data = {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      };
      var email = this.state.email;
      var password = this.state.password;

      const errors = loginUserValidation(data);

      if (errors) {
        this.setState({errors: errors});
      } else {
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            this.setState({ loginError: error.reason });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="registration-form-container">
        <Row>
          <Col sm={8} smOffset={2} md={6} mdOffset={3}>

            <div className="paper">
              <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <section className="form-title">
                  <h3 className="text-center">Login</h3>
                </section>
                <hr />
                <section className="form-content-login-or-registration">

                  {this.state.loginError &&
                    <div className="alert alert-danger">
                      <p>{this.state.loginError}</p>
                    </div>
                  }

                  <SingleInput
                    name={'email'}
                    inputType={'email'}
                    controlFunc={this.handleInputChange}
                    content={this.state.email}
                    placeholder={'Email'}
                    bsSize={null}
                    error={this.state.errors && this.state.errors.email}
                  />

                  <SingleInput
                    name={'password'}
                    inputType={'password'}
                    controlFunc={this.handleInputChange}
                    content={this.state.password}
                    placeholder={'Password'}
                    bsSize={null}
                    error={this.state.errors && this.state.errors.password}
                  />
                </section>
                <section className="form-buttons">
                  <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" block>Login</Button>
                </section>
              </Form>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that all you have for LoginForm? Can you put the whole code in there?

Comment: The complete code for the component, and anything it interacts with, or interacts with it, is usually useful when debugging.

Comment: @KyleRichardson. See update

Comment: @D-reaper see update

Comment: @KyleRichardson, would you mind showing me that. Still new to react.

Comment: @bp123 actually never mind that is not the problem. I did find it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Meteor.loginWithPassword` changes your `logginIn` value to true, your `<Public />` component unmounts your wrapped `<LoginForm />`

```
const Public = ({ loggingIn, authenticated, component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      if (loggingIn) return <div />; // <--- this right here
      return !authenticated ?
      (React.createElement(component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated })) :
      (<Redirect to="/" />);
    }}
  />
);
```

So `loggingIn` values changes causing `<Public />` to re-render. Now that `loggingIn` is true, you render a div instead of the component that was, unmounting it and making `setState`unavailable when the errors callback tries to invoke it.

EDIT: In response to your comment...

To prevent this you can handle the error display inside the `<LoginForm />`

1. Remove `if (loggingIn) return <div />;` from your `<Route />` in your `<Public />` component.
2. Inside your `<LoginForm />` you can handle the error condition. Do this by making a component that displays your errors and include it in your `<LoginForm />` component where you want it displayed. Make the `<ErrorDisplay />` component return nothing if there are no errors.

Example `<ErrorDisplay />` component

```
const ErrorDisplay = ({ errors }) => {
    errors && <div className="error-container">{ errors }</div>
};
```

That is obviously barebones, but I hope it helps you understand!

Comment: That makes sense. How could I write it to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Side note: You should create this `React.createElement(component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated })` component outside of your the render of your `<Route />`

Comment: Great! That is the problem. As for your side note, can you show me what you mean? I'd be happy to write up a question if you prefer.

Comment: I think that qualifies as a separate question. Or you can figure out how to invite me to chat in SO lol.

Comment: thanks again - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272593/render-component-outside-of-route