# Render component outside of Route

Tags: reactjs

I have a Public and Authenticated function that I use to control authentication with react router v4 and it has been pointed out to me that I should create this `React.createElement(component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated })` component outside of the render of `<Route />`. I'm not sure how or why I should do this. Please explain and show?

```
const Public = ({ loggingIn, authenticated, component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      return !authenticated ?
      (React.createElement(component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated })) :
      (<Redirect to="/" />);
    }}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you since you already have a component you're passing into `<Public />` to be rendered here. Change the `component` to `Component` considering it is a user defined element.

This is from the React documentation [User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

```
const Public = ({ loggingIn, authenticated, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      return !authenticated ?
      (<Component loggingIn={ loggingIn } authenticated={ authenticated } { ...rest } />) :
      (<Redirect to="/" />);
    }}
  />
);
```

Comment: I get an error `Unexpected token, expected ...` on the `<Component` line

Comment: You might have to look at the updated code, I forgot a closing `>` on my first post that I just updated.

Comment: error in console. `You should not use <Route component> and <Route render> in the same route; <Route render> will be ignored`

Comment: Check edit, changed `const Public = ({ loggingIn, authenticated, component: Component, ...rest })` so that the `component` is passed with lower case as to not cause that problem, but is still usable as `Component` inside